# Why can't I generate a map using JavaFX textfields by calling the method from another Class?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, linkedhashmap, java-12

*I'm a java/programming newby.

I've written the following code examples to try to figure out my problem and then give clear examples of my issue.  I want to have my program divided into separate classes based on their functions within the application:
Main
MainController - drives the JavaFX GUI.
Initialiser - semantic validation of entered data.
Model - performs calculations on the data and sends results back to MainController.

Where I'm stuck is that the initialiser, specifically the linkedhashmap and first validation check, throw a nullpointerexception.  This DOESN'T happen if everything is in a single class (I started with everything in one class now am learning how to structure in separate classes, etc.).  It also DOESN'T happen if I don't use any JavaFX features.

**For example, this works:**

```
package helloWorld;
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");

        HashmapExample hashy = new HashmapExample();

        System.out.println(hashy.initialiser());
    }
}
```

```
package helloWorld;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashmapExample {

    private Map<String,String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public void mapper() {

    testMap.put("one","a");
    testMap.put("two","b");
    testMap.put("three","c");

    }

    public String initialiser() {

        mapper();

        String errorField = testMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isBlank()).map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst().orElse(null);

        String message;

        if (errorField != null) {
            return message = errorField + " blank!";
        } else {
            return message = "OK!";
        }

    }

}
```

**But this doesn't:**

```
package helloWorldFX;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = (VBox)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainGUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
package helloWorldFX;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class MainController {

    @FXML private TextArea outputMessage;

    public void run(ActionEvent event) {

        Initialiser initialiser = new Initialiser();

        outputMessage.setText(initialiser.checker());

    }

}
```

```
package helloWorldFX;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Initialiser {

    @FXML   private TextField one;
    @FXML   private TextField two;
    @FXML   private TextField three;

private Map<TextField,String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public void mapper() {

    testMap.put(one,"a");
    testMap.put(two,"b");
    testMap.put(three,"c");

    }

    public String checker() {

        mapper();

        String errorField = testMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getText().isBlank()).map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst().orElse(null);

        String message;

        if (errorField != null) {
            return message = errorField + " blank!";
        } else {
            return message = "OK!";
        }

    }

}
```

When I do a coverage run in eclipse, I can tell it is probably caused by the line
`String errorField = testMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isBlank()).map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst().orElse(null);`
but I'm not completely sure.

I've just noticed in scene builder that the fields 'one', 'two', and 'three' don't appear as valid ID's for the text fields, because they aren't in the MainController class.  This must have something to do with the issue, but I don't understand how to fix it.

**FXML file, as requested:** just remember, its a set of example code, not meant to be a real program, so the layout is nonsensical.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="helloWorldFX.MainController">
   <children>
      <TextField />
      <TextField />
      <TextField />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#run" text="Button" />
      <TextArea fx:id="outputMessage" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Error messages:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at helloWorldFX.Initialiser.lambda$0(Initialiser.java:29)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at helloWorldFX.Initialiser.checker(Initialiser.java:29)
    at helloWorldFX.MainController.run(MainController.java:15)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: What does your `MainGUI.fxml` file look like?

Comment: @Avi added fxml file as requested.

Comment: Please post stack trace of your `NullPointerException`. Debugging the cause of an exception _always_ starts with looking at the stack trace.

Comment: Your LinkedHashMap is probably fine (if it were null, the mapper(); call would throw an exception). The problem is probably with the content of the map, make sure you do not retrieve null values (or check against null values). My bet is on a non null TextField with a null Text.

Comment: @Abra is that what you mean by stack trace?  I listed the console error message output.

Comment: From the stack trace you posted, the line of your code throwing the exception is line 29 in file `Initialiser.java`

Comment: @Abra yeah that's the `String errorField = testMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry ->` etc. expression.  It seems to refer to the lambda part of the code, which contains the `getText` method.  The whole reason I was building the validator was because `getText` gives a `nullpointerexception` if you leave the `TextField` blank.  This doesn't seem to be a problem in the validator when everything is kept together, but running it as a method of another class causes drama for some reason.

Comment: you are missing to load the Initializer (or else let it self-load in its constructor) - just instantiating doesn't (how could it without knowing its fxml) inject the fields.

Comment: @kleopatra See my answer below.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work-around:**

So based on the comments and some more thought on what could be the cause, I've come up with this work-around.

I instantiate and populate the `Map` in the MainController, then instantiate the Initialiser class, which now takes the `Map` as a parameter via the constructor.  Then I call the checker method from the Initialiser object, which runs the semantic check on the data that was sent to the object when it was instantiated.

As far as I can tell, the issue is that one fxml file can only deal with one controller class, so you can't populate the map with `TextFields` from anywhere except the main controller class.  If you do, the `getText` method will throw `nullpointerexception` because it is pointing to `TextFields` that don't technically exist in the fxml.

**See the amended code:**

```
package helloWorldFX;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainController {

    @FXML   private TextField one;
    @FXML   private TextField two;
    @FXML   private TextField three;

    @FXML   private TextArea outputMessage;

    public void run(ActionEvent event) {

        Map<TextField, String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        testMap.put(one,"a");
        testMap.put(two,"b");
        testMap.put(three,"c");

        Initialiser initialiser = new Initialiser(testMap);

        outputMessage.setText(initialiser.checker());

    }

}
```

```
package helloWorldFX;

import java.util.Map;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Initialiser {

    private Map<TextField, String> values;

    public Initialiser(Map<TextField, String> mappedValues) {
        this.values = mappedValues;
    }

    String message;

    public String checker() {

        String errorField = values.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().getText().isBlank()).map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (errorField != null) {
            return message = errorField + " blank!";
        } else {
            return message = "OK!";
        }

    }

}
```

At this point, because of my lack of experience, I don't know if this is actually a work-around or the true correct way to do it - maybe someone can help fill that part in.